# Redefine window property in separate entry points for typescript

Tags: typescript, webpack

I'd like to pass data from a template to a typescript file during the initial page load by attaching data to the `window` object (e.g. see [this use of window.props](https://hackernoon.com/reconciling-djangos-mvc-templates-with-react-components-3aa986cf510a)). I'd also like each page to reuse the same variable name for this page-specific data (`window.data` below).

In the typescript file used as an entry point for one page (e.g `foo.ts`), I'd declare data on the `window` object with:

```js
declare global {
    interface Window {
        data: {
            foo: string;
        };
    }
}
```

And on another page (e.g `bar.ts`), I'd declare:

```js
declare global {
    interface Window {
        data: {
            bar: int;
        };
    }
}
```

These typescript files (`foo.ts` and `bar.ts`) would be declared as separate [entry points in webpack](https://webpack.js.org/concepts/entry-points/). When compiling this, I see the following error:

```
TS2717: Subsequent property declarations must have the same type.  Property 'data' must be of type '{ bar: string; }', but here has type '{ foo: string; }'.
```

Other than using a unique name for each of these objects, is there a way to avoid these errors?

Answer (score 2):

> Other than using a unique name for each of these objects, is there a way to avoid these errors?

You cannot redeclare `data` to be two different types. Fix would be to declare then to be of the same interface and use interface declaration merging:

// File A

```
declare global {
    interface IData { 
      foo: string;
    }
    interface Window {
        data: IData;
    }
}
```

// File B:

```
declare global {
    interface IData { 
      bar: number;
    }
    interface Window {
        data: IData;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't have two contradictory sources of truth in one TypeScript project. This makes it cumbersome to model different execution environments, but there is good news: you can work your way around it.

Ask yourself this: *when* is `Data` different? When you figure out the answer to that question, you can model your environment in a way that reflects your use case.

**Scenario one: you have more than on project, but only one `tsconfig.json`**

If you have defined a single `tsconfig.json` project, but that project is executed under different conditions, you may benefit from splitting your project into smaller projects with their own respective `tsconfig.json` files. You can find an example of such a *composite project* [here](https://github.com/RyanCavanaugh/project-references-demo).

For example, a *composite project* could consist of 3 projects.

- server code
- client code
- tests

The global object can be different for each of those. You just have to augment `Window` on a per-project basis, and the augmentation will apply to the code that lives in the related directory.

**Scenario two: you have one environment and `data` can actually be one of two types**

If that is the case, then the intellectually honest way to model your `Window` is to say:

```
declare global {
  interface Window {
    data: { foo: string } | { bar: number };
  }
}
```

However, this won't allow you to access neither `window.data.foo` nor `window.data.bar` — because neither property is safe to be accessed. TypeScript doesn't know when they're there.

To work around that, you can use *assertion signatures* in the modules that rely on a specific environment.

```
function assert(condition: boolean): asserts condition {
  if (!condition) {
    throw new Error('Assertion failed');
  }
}
```

```
assert('foo' in window.data);

// Now we can access foo
window.data.foo;

// But not bar
window.data.bar;
```

This, however, will work only on a per-module basis. You will need to assert your environment in every file that relies on a specific value of `window.data`.